# Intellij JSF ("h:") tags not displaying

Tags: jsf, intellij-idea

i am trying to run my first JSF Hello World Project in Intellij.
My Problem is that all JSF Tags like h: is not displaying in browser.
I do have mojarra 2.2.1 and JSF in my Project Structure
and I also have Tomcat 8.5.3 integrated in my Intellij Project

```
hello-world.xhtml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE html
    PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"
    "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
    xmlns:h="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/html"
    xmlns:a="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/passthrough">

<h:head>
    <title>Hello World</title>
</h:head>
<h:body>
   <h:outputText value="jhjhjhjhjj"/>
   <h:form>
       <h:inputText id="name" value="#{theUserName}" a:placeholder="What`s your name?"/>
       <h:commandButton value="Submit" action="myresponse"/>
   </h:form>
</h:body>
</html>
```

And here`s my web.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee                     http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_1.xsd"
     version="3.1">

<servlet>
    <servlet-name>FacesServlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>
        javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet
    </servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>FacesServlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>*.jsf</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
<context-param>
    <param-name>javax.faces.PROJECT_STAGE</param-name>
    <param-value>Development</param-value>
</context-param>

</web-app>
```

I just had a look into the deployed index.xhtml which is in the out folder tomcat produces while deploying
and the following name spaces in the html tag are red highlighted
in there:

```
    xmlns:h="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/html"
```

comes the message: 
     "Resource is not registered by this is uri is not recognized

and for those two

```
  xmlns:ui="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/facelets"
  xmlns:f="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/core">
```

comes the message: URI is not registered. I tried to register them in the settings but its not possible.

Comment: What all library you added in lib folder ?

Comment: javax.faces-2.2.1.jar
javax.persistence.jar
jstl-1.1.0.jar